# How to populate cookies infos from SignupPage to the Navbar component with Next.js^9.3?

Tags: reactjs, authorization, next.js

I'm struggling since 2 days to implement authentication.
I use **Strapi as a headless CMS/backend.** I use **next.js@9.3.4** for the frontend.

I found out a package called **nookie** from a tutorial.
I have a **signup page** where I've implemented nookies but since I want to show the **username** and a **link** to let the user to **logout** out, I've decided to put everything within **React context** (don't know if it's a good idea).

Everything works fine until I **refresh the page.** The **cookie is still here** but the **Username and the link dissapear**

**Here is the signup page**

```
    import cogoToast from 'cogo-toast';
    import Router from 'next/router';
    import { parseCookies } from 'nookies';
    import styled from 'styled-components';
    import FormStyles from '../components/styles/FormStyles';
    import Title from '../components/Title';
    import { signupUser } from '../lib/api';
    import useForm from '../lib/useForm';
    import { useInfos } from './context/LocalState';
    // import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

    const Column = styled.div`
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(350px, 1fr));
      gap: 20px;
    `;

    const SignUpPage = () => {
      const { inputs, handleChange, clearForm } = useForm({
        username: 'machin',
        email: 'machin@850g.com',
        password: 'azerty123',
      });

      const { userLogin } = useInfos();
      const isEmpty = !inputs.username || !inputs.email || !inputs.password;

      const handleSubmit = async e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const res = await signupUser(
          inputs.username,
          inputs.email,
          inputs.password
        );
        userLogin(res);
        clearForm();
      };
      return (
        <Column>
          <FormStyles method="post" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <fieldset>
              <Title title="Se creer un Compte" center />

              {isEmpty && (
                <p className="form-empty">Pense a remplir tous les champs</p>
              )}
              <label htmlFor="username">
                Username
                <input
                  type="text"
                  name="username"
                  value={inputs.username}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  autoComplete="name"
                />
              </label>
              <label htmlFor="email">
                Email
                <input
                  type="email"
                  name="email"
                  value={inputs.email}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  autoComplete="email"
                />
              </label>
              <label htmlFor="password">
                Password
                <input
                  type="password"
                  name="password"
                  value={inputs.password}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  autoComplete="new-password"
                />
              </label>
              {!isEmpty && <button type="submit">Sign Up</button>}
            </fieldset>
          </FormStyles>
        </Column>
      );
    };

    SignUpPage.getInitialProps = ctx => {
      const isAuthenticated = parseCookies(ctx).coookiePapi;
      console.log({ isAuthenticated });

      // When the user is authenticated, don't let the user visit the
      // sign-in and sign-up routes
      if (isAuthenticated && ['/signup', '/signin'].indexOf(ctx.asPath) > -1) {
        if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
          Router.push('/');
          cogoToast.info("You're already logged papi");
        } else if (ctx.res) {
          ctx.res.writeHead(301, {
            Location: '/',
          });
          ctx.res.end();
        }
      }
      return {};
    };

    export default SignUpPage;
```

**My 2 functions from React Context**

```js
    const userLogin = info => (
    setCookie(null, 'coookiePapi', info.jwt, {
    maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60,
    path: '/',
    }),
    setUser(info),
    info.jwt
    ? cogoToast.success("great {info.user.username}!")
    : cogoToast.error("Something went wrong"),
    Router.push('/')
    );

    const userLogout = () => (
    destroyCookie(null, 'cookiePapi'),
    Router.push('/'),
    setUser([]),
    cogoToast.success('See you soon')
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The react app context will reset on a page refresh and you'll need to write your own `persistence` logic. I'm not sure what your `setUser` function does, but the you need to do two things:

a) Write to storage on login when the user state changes. We can achieve this through an effect hook (when userState changes, persist it to localStorage):

```
useEffect(() => {
  localStorage.setItem('userState', JSON.stringify(userDetails))
}, [userDetails])
```

b) Update your context / state code to restore from localStorage. For example,

```
let initialUserState = {}
try {
  initialUserState = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('userState'))
} catch(e) { // do nothing }
const [userState, setUserState] = useState(initialUserState);
```

[use-persisted-state](https://github.com/donavon/use-persisted-state) simplifies this process, and also provides you with helpers to work with in-app state and storage syncing.

Since you are treating localStorage or sessionStorage as a store, you can effectively move away from a global app context, and use a custom-made hook, for example `useUserState`, inside components that need to reference your userState.